# R: How to subset the string in a dataframe column?

Tags: r

Samples are either wild-type or mutant. I want to find the number of samples that are wild-type `wt` versus mutant `mut` with respect to the respondents `Responder` in the `Group1` column of the `res.sig` dataframe. In the `n_mutated_group1` column, the first letter indicates the number of mutant and the last two digits (after `or`) indicates the total number for that group. `wt` is the difference between `total` and `mut`.

```
# Number of samples in wild-type versus mutant with respect to the most significantly enriched genes 
total <- sum(as.numeric(res.sig %>%
                       filter(Group1=="Responder") %>%
                       mutate(last_letter = substr(n_mutated_group1,-2,-1)) %>%
                       pull(last_letter)))

mut <- sum(as.numeric(res.sig %>%
                        filter(Group1=="Responder") %>%
                        mutate(first_letter = substr(n_mutated_group1,1,1)) %>%
                        pull(first_letter)))

wt <- total-mut
```

res.sig

```
> dput(res.sig)
structure(list(Hugo_Symbol = c("ERCC2", "ERCC2", "AKAP9", "AKAP9", 
"HERC1", "HERC1", "HECTD1", "HECTD1", "MACF1", "MACF1", "MROH2B", 
"MROH2B", "KMT2C", "KMT2C"), Group1 = c("Non-Responder", "Responder", 
"Non-Responder", "Responder", "Non-Responder", "Responder", "Non-Responder", 
"Responder", "Non-Responder", "Responder", "Non-Responder", "Responder", 
"Non-Responder", "Responder"), Group2 = c("Rest", "Rest", "Rest", 
"Rest", "Rest", "Rest", "Rest", "Rest", "Rest", "Rest", "Rest", 
"Rest", "Rest", "Rest"), n_mutated_group1 = c("0 of 25", "9 of 25", 
"0 of 25", "6 of 25", "0 of 25", "6 of 25", "0 of 25", "6 of 25", 
"0 of 25", "6 of 25", "0 of 25", "6 of 25", "1 of 25", "7 of 25"
), n_mutated_group2 = c("9 of 25", "0 of 25", "6 of 25", "0 of 25", 
"6 of 25", "0 of 25", "6 of 25", "0 of 25", "6 of 25", "0 of 25", 
"6 of 25", "0 of 25", "7 of 25", "1 of 25"), p_value = c(0.00163083541184905, 
0.00163083541184905, 0.022289766970618, 0.022289766970618, 0.022289766970618, 
0.022289766970618, 0.022289766970618, 0.022289766970618, 0.022289766970618, 
0.022289766970618, 0.022289766970618, 0.022289766970618, 0.0487971536957187, 
0.0487971536957187), OR = c(0, Inf, 0, Inf, 0, Inf, 0, Inf, 0, 
Inf, 0, Inf, 0.111488645279478, 8.96952328636894), OR_low = c(0, 
2.56647319276964, 0, 1.33358819424024, 0, 1.33358819424024, 0, 
1.33358819424024, 0, 1.33358819424024, 0, 1.33358819424024, 0.00228988507629356, 
1.0079479819766), OR_high = c(0.38963976043749, Inf, 0.749856668137133, 
Inf, 0.749856668137133, Inf, 0.749856668137133, Inf, 0.749856668137133, 
Inf, 0.749856668137133, Inf, 0.992114690322592, 436.703138665198
), fdr = c(0.109265972593886, 0.109265972593886, 0.248902397838568, 
0.248902397838568, 0.248902397838568, 0.248902397838568, 0.248902397838568, 
0.248902397838568, 0.248902397838568, 0.248902397838568, 0.248902397838568, 
0.248902397838568, 0.467058471087594, 0.467058471087594)), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000002adab171ef0>)
```

Problem:

Here, I'm getting `total` as `NA_real_` instead of the total number.

Comment: Unfortunately using negative numbers in `substr` does not work. You could use `substr(n_mutated_group1,nchar(n_mutated_group1)-1, nchar(n_mutated_group1))` to obtain the last 2 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract for `total` everything after the `of` string in your column and for `mut` you can extract everything before `of`. You can use this code:

```
library(tidyverse)
  total <- sum(as.numeric(res.sig %>%
                          filter(Group1=="Responder") %>%
                          mutate(first_letter = sub('.+of(.+)', '\\1', n_mutated_group1)) %>%
                          pull(first_letter)))
  
  mut <- sum(as.numeric(res.sig %>%
                            filter(Group1 == "Responder") %>%
                            mutate(last_letter = sub("\\of.*", "", n_mutated_group1)) %>%
                            pull(last_letter)))
  
  wt <- total-mut
  wt
```

Output wt:

```
[1] 129
```